# Joining table to entity

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpql

I would like to get the result of this SQL query in an entity:

```
SELECT * FROM thethreads t
LEFT JOIN thread_votes tv
ON t.idthread=tv.thread
AND tv.from_user like "currentUser";
```

Note that the joined result isn't part of my thethreads table:

[image]

I've tried this :

```
private static final String SELECT_NEWEST_THREADS = "Select t From Thethread t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.threadcurrentUserVote tv WHERE tv.user1=:currentUser ORDER BY t.datePosted";
```

and I've added this to my Thethread entity (which isn't a column in my table):

```
@OneToOne
private ThreadVote threadcurrentUserVote;
```

but I get an error :`Unknown column 't1.THREADCURRENTUSERVOTE_id_votes_thread' in 'field list'`

The purpose is to see if the user visiting a thread has already voted it or not.

Comment: By default the onetoone (unidirectional) maps to a column/field in the entity's table, where you set the annotations, named like it is mentioned in the error message. How do you want to map the one-to-one association between Thethread and ThreadVote? Where do you want to set field that represent this association?

Comment: @Guillermo I want the Thethread entity to have a ThreadVote, so I can know if the user voted or not. Does that answer your question ? If the user voted then it has a threadvote if not then it is null. Like in the SQL query I posted.

Comment: I think your jpa mapping is wrong. I will write another mapping to solve this case. Correct me if I miss understand something

Comment: @Guillermo Oh yeah my mapping is wrong, that's the point, I don't know how I should handle the mapping for this case. I've bean searching a lot for 2 days now but I still don't know. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding well, you have many ThreadVote per Thethdread and you are trying to find out if exists a vote from a known user for the thread.

So instead of define the one-to-one you mention add this to your `ThreadVote` entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="thread")
 private Thethread thread;
```

Assuming that you have an association ThreadVote -> User called `user1` that represents the *from_user*. The next query gets the thdreads that have been voted by the *current User*

```
select t
from ThreadVote tv join  tv.thread t 
where tv.user1 = :currentUser 
order by t.datePosted
```

**Edit**

I am a little lazy, but you could also add the next mapping into the `Thethread` entity to make the association bidirectional
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="thread")
    private votes;

Then the next query gets the pair `thdread` and a vaule that indicates if the current user has vote for the thdread

```
select t, 
  case
    when ( tv is not empty and :currentUser in tv.user1 ) then TRUE
    else FALSE
  end
from Thethread t left outer join t.votes tv
order by t.datePosted
```

I'm not sure if the *when*'s condition expression is all right because it use collection path.  If it cause any problems you can replace it by some useful subquery

Comment: The thing is that I want to display threads, so I'm querying the 10 latest threads. For each Thread I would like to know if the user voted or not (if there is a ThreadVote then the user voted, if it's null then the user didn't). So I'll look further into this.

Comment: ok I got it working, unfortunately, your answer wasn't what I was looking for exactly. But since you put me in the right direction ( and I thank you for that ) it's only fair you have the answer as accepted. So here is what I did, I just changed the query to this : "Select t From Thethread t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.threadVotes tv ON tv.user1=:currentUser ORDER BY t.datePosted" . I'll accept your answer when edited. Cheers and thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read this. Seems that I don't understand what you want. If you find out the solution just share it in a new answer. For welcome!